# Sending Mail in Android Intent Without Pressing Send Button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intentservice

i was creating Android Intent Mail. i am getting all the subject, to , mail body in email. is there is any possibility to send the mail without pressing send button . [image]

My code is :

```
 public void Sendmail(HashMap s) {

        HashMap<String, String> sss = s;

        String[] toppings = new String[sss.size()];

        int size1 = 0;

        for (String key : sss.keySet()) {

            toppings[size1] = key + "\n" + sss.get(key) + "\n";
            System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + sss.get(key));


            size1++;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s3 : toppings) {
            builder.append(s3);
        }
        String mbody = builder.toString();


        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setType("plain/text");

        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Task Activity");
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mbody);
        i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"hari.andoidsaiss@gmail.com"});

        try {
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. A user should know what he is sending. Also a user should be aware about his actions.

You can do it using API and sending Email from server.

Comment: Can u give me any API source example ?

Comment: sure he can, with sms its the same. He can. Of course I will not recommend it.

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan I am not an API developer.. My Backend Developer create API for me. you can tell your API developer..they know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Share Intent of Android as it will populate installed app from your device which can process your data.

You can achieve this by following ways:

1. Implement mail client to send emails from your server side. ex: [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/).
2. Integrate API's like **[Javamail](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-email-app-using-javamail-api-in-android-studio/)** or **[Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)** to your android app to get your work done.